# Visual Studio 2017, JavaScript intellisense inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-2017, tsconfig

**TL;DR**: How do you include a tsconfig.json file in Visual Studio 2017 and still have JavaScript intellisense work like it does by default, giving code hints both for your own code and 3rd-party libraries? Is it borked, or do I just need a better understanding of how it works?

Much like jQuery, I would like ubiquitous access to my own JavaScript namespaces across JavaScript and html files with intellisense. How does one achieve this?

---

**EDIT 3**:
I reported this issue on [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search.html?f=&type=question%20OR%20problem&type=question%20OR%20problem&c=&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=javascript%20intellisense). Please consider up-voting the issue to attract more attention from Microsoft.

---

**EDIT 2**:
Currently the "solution" is Resharper, which provides what one would expect straight out-of-the-box. But it's not really ideal at a price of $299/yr/user for something Visual Studio markets it provides itself.

---

**EDIT 1:**
In the event that my expectations for JavaScript intellisense in Visual Studio is inaccurate, below is a contrived example of how I expect it to function.

Say I create three TypeScript files in my ./Scripts folder, we'll call them *A.ts*, *B.ts*, and *C.ts*. Each will contain its own namespace:

A.ts

```
namespace A {
    export function f1(s: string) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

B.ts

```
namespace B {
    export function f1(n: number) {
        return n;
    }
}
```

C.ts

```
namespace C {
    export function f1(b: boolean) {
        return b;
    }
}
```

At this point in time one may expect to be able to start seeing intellisense for their newly created namespaces, and indeed, within A.ts, B.ts, and C.ts you begin to see intellisense for those namespaces. Cool.

[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't carry over to other places, like /Home/Index.cshtml. Index.cshtml knows nothing about the A, B, or C namespaces. Additionally, .js files know nothing about these namespaces, hence the need for their respective TypeScript Declaration (.d.ts) files.

So we'll go ahead and add our tsconfig.json file to the root of our project and configure it like we do above. If we perform an edit on one of our .ts files and save it, this triggers the compilation of our corresponding .d.ts files into our ./Scripts/out folder. Do we now get intellisense in Index.cshtml and .js files? ...No.

Now you might be thinking these files need to be included in the project in order for Visual Studio to pick them up for intellisense (they're excluded on creation). So you include them in the project. Intellisense? No. jQuery intellisense? No. Perhaps they need to be in the same directory as the file you want to use them in? .....Kind of? I've ran into intellisense being inconsistent like this on a number of occassions:

[image]

Somehow we're getting intellisense for our 'A' namespace within our C3.js (note: a JavaScript file), but none of the other ones. What?

Perhaps you think you're on the right track and that you've scored a small victory against the intellisense engine. But then you restart your Visual Studio instance and...

[image]

Wait....I *just* had intellisense for the 'A' namespace. What happened!?

I have no idea. But after messing around for a bit I try placing an import statement at the top of the .js file, and all of a sudden intellisense starts kicking in for the imported files/modules. Huzzah!

[image]

And even in Index.cshtml I begin receiving intellisense for our imported namespaces.

[image]

The moment I close the .js file with the import statements, though, all of a sudden I lose the intellisense for them in Index.cshtml. Wait...what?? And unlike in JavaScript files, I'm unable to write an import statement to receive intellisense for them:

[image]

Or at least... not with my own namespaces:

[image]

It's this inconsistent back-and-forth that confuses the heck out of me as to how exactly Visual Studio's JavaScript intellisense actually works. I still don't know if it's just broken or if I need a better understanding of it.

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

**System**
Windows 10
VS2017 15.0.0+26228.10
New JavaScript language service is enabled

I've been fighting to get Visual Studio 2017's JavaScript intellisense to work for me for a couple of days now to no avail. I don't know if something's genuinely wonky with the IDE or if I just don't understand it properly.

My understanding of [how VS2017's JS intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense) works is now by typescript definition files, or .d.ts files. Ultimately I would like to get intellisense to help us out with our own TypeScript/JavaScript but right now I'd settle for just having it work consistently within a fresh project.

If I create a new ASP.NET MVC 4.5.2 project, out-of-the-box JS intellisense seems to work fine, and by that I mean I can type a dollar sign ($) either in a .js file or between <*script*> tags and I properly receive intellisense for jQuery. Awesome. Now, with the ultimate goal in mind of creating TypeScript files (.ts) and having the TypeScript compiler generate our .d.ts files automagically so that we can get rich intellisense for our own code, I wish to introduce a tsconfig.json file to the root of the project in order to configure that.

After creating the tsconfig.json file JS intellisense ceases to function. I type a dollar sign ($) into either a .js file or between <*script*> tags and I get zero intellisense for jQuery. This was a frustrating experience for a while but then I read this little note found on the linked page above:

> NOTE: This feature is disabled by default if using a tsconfig.json
> configuration file, but may be set to enabled as outlined further
> below).

"This feature" is in reference to "By default, the Salsa language service will try to detect which JavaScript libraries are in use...in order to provide richer IntelliSense." Ok, so the Salsa language service will *not* autodetect libraries in use and provide intellisense for them when a tsconfig.json file is present, unless you specifically configure it to do so as "outlined below." At least, that's how I understand it.

If we scroll down the page a little bit and come to the tsconfig file settings we come across a setting for *enableAutoDiscovery* which "enables the automatic detection and download of definition files as outlined above." It's not super explicit as to what "as outlined above" is in reference to, but I can only assume it's in reference to the previous note indicative of re-enabling Salsa's auto-detection feature to provide rich intellisense. So I include that option in my tsconfig.json file and...no benefit; still no JS intellisense.

As it turns out, [*typingOptions.enableAutoDiscovery* has been renamed to *typeAcquisition.enable*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12373). Grrrrr. Alright, so we make that change in our tsconfig.json aaaaaaand... still no JS intellisense.

At this point I *am* able to write my own .d.ts files and Visual Studio's intellisense will pick it up alright (most of the time...), but I still have no intellisense for 3rd-party libraries like jQuery, which is no good.

So far I've landed on the following tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./Scripts/out"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true, 
    "include": ["jquery"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./Scripts/app/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./Scripts/vendors/**/*",
    "./Scripts/out/**/*"
  ]
}
```

With the TypeScript virtual project in view I can see that my project's .ts files are included as well as jQuery in my %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules@types directory.

[image: TypeScript Virtual Project]

I was hopeful that with all this in place I would have both intellisense for my own project's .ts files and 3rd-party libraries (at least those specifically included; jQuery only at this point). Alas...no. Still no jQuery intellisense.

Incidentally, if I write an import line for jQuery, all of a sudden I get jQuery intellisense

[image]

...interesting. And maybe that makes perfect sense; I haven't messed a whole lot with module imports and how Visual Studio's intellisense handles those, but what I *really* want is to have intellisense application-wide for both our code and 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same behaviour. I had intellisense for my namespaces for awhile. And all of a sudden I lost all of them. Can't figure out how it reads and builds up intellisense for javascript/typescript in vs 2017

Comment: It's June now, of course. I'm wondering if you have made any progress on this issue? I was able to get Intellisense to work in VS2017, with a tsconfig.json file, after modifying the project file's TypeScriptToolsVersion node to 2.2. What is your tools version set to?

Answer (score 1):

JS files are for javascript and are not transpiled using the typescript compiler.

If you are using typescript then keep all your typescript in ts files.

Also, you shouldn't put typescript inside your cshtml files because typescript is not javascript. You need to use the typescript compiler to transpile your typescript into javascript which you can then use that javascript inside your HTML pages.

I think what you are trying to do is not a way typically how people use typescript.  Usually you write all your typescript in TS files and then as a build process you transpile all your typescript into javascript. There are many strategies on how to do this. You can bundle all your javascript into one file or break them up into modules. There is a lot of options on how you want your final javascript output to look.

Your CSHTML views would reference your compiled javascript and not your typescript.  The browser doesn't know what to do w/ typescript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the latest update March 14, 2017 (build 26228.09) caused this issue, you can go to Control Panel—Programs and Features-View Installed updates and remove this update, then reopen VS to check the intellisense. If it works, which means this update lead to this issue, you can temporarily not install this updat

I've noticed the Microsoft Report Projects for Visual Studio Extension can cause problems such as this when being used in a project, A couple of mine have broken right after I add my SQL Server Report project to the solution and restarted visual studio..  So for now I remove my Report project from the solution but I hope Microsoft fixes this issue

Comment: Are there any sources to verify said update actually broke JavaScript intellisense? Regardless, I don't appear to have that update installed anyways, so that's not it. And as was mentioned, all of the above steps were followed in a fresh ASP.NET MVC 4.5.2 project; no additional projects were added to the solution.

Comment: It's listed in the known issues for VS2017 currently:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#knownissues

Look for the title: JavaScript IntelliSense stops working